# Why is adding sorted columns to an index not making it more efficient?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance, postgresql-11

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT  "cars"."id" FROM de."cars" 
WHERE "cars"."sales_state" = 'onsale'
  AND (cars.is_disabled IS NOT TRUE) 
  AND (cars.price >= 35920) 
  AND (cars.price <= 659880) 
  AND ("cars"."featuring_score" IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN cars.featuring_score < 'C' THEN 1
        WHEN cars.featuring_score = 'C' THEN 2
        WHEN cars.featuring_score > 'C' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
   END, 
   CASE WHEN cars.au_rating >= 3 THEN 1
        WHEN cars.au_rating = 0  THEN 2
        WHEN cars.au_rating = 2  THEN 3
        WHEN cars.au_rating = 1  THEN 4
        ELSE 6
   END, 
   CASE cars.brand
        WHEN 'Audi' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Alpina' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Artega' THEN 3
        WHEN 'BMW' THEN 4
        WHEN 'Maybach' THEN 5
        ELSE 6
   END ASC, 
   CASE WHEN ABS(cars.price - 347900) < cars.price * 0.2 THEN 1
        WHEN ABS(cars.price - 347900) < cars.price * 0.4 THEN 2
        WHEN ABS(cars.price - 347900) < cars.price * 0.6 THEN 3
        ELSE 4
   END, 
   CASE WHEN images_count = 0 OR images_count IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END,
   ABS(cars.price - 347900) 
LIMIT 61;
```

I'm trying to create an index that will make this query execute faster. The thing I'm puzzled about is why the following two indexes are equally fast, and has the exec same query plan:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS index_cars_v2
        ON de.cars USING btree
        (
          (price)
        )
        WHERE sales_state::text = 'onsale'::text 
           AND is_disabled IS NOT TRUE 
           AND featuring_score IS NOT NULL
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS index_cars_v2
        ON de.cars USING btree
        (
          (CASE WHEN cars.featuring_score < 'C' THEN 1 WHEN cars.featuring_score = 'C' THEN 2 WHEN cars.featuring_score > 'C' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END),
          (CASE WHEN cars.au_rating >= 3 THEN 1 WHEN cars.au_rating = 0 THEN 2 WHEN cars.au_rating = 2 THEN 3 WHEN cars.au_rating = 1 THEN 4 ELSE 6 END),
          (price)
        )
        WHERE sales_state::text = 'onsale'::text 
           AND is_disabled IS NOT TRUE 
           AND featuring_score IS NOT NULL
```

Both produce a query plan something like this:

```
"Limit  (cost=326.63..326.78 rows=61 width=28) (actual time=218.501..218.508 rows=61 loops=1)"
"  Output: id, (CASE WHEN ((featuring_score)::text < 'C'::text) THEN 1 WHEN ((featuring_score)::text = 'C'::text) THEN 2 WHEN ((featuring_score)::text > 'C'::text) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END), (CASE WHEN (au_rating >= 3) THEN 1 WHEN (au_rating = 0) THEN 2 WHEN (au_rating = 2) THEN 3 WHEN (au_rating = 1) THEN 4 ELSE 6 END), (CASE brand WHEN 'Audi'::text THEN 1 WHEN 'Alpina'::text THEN 2 WHEN 'Artega'::text THEN 3 WHEN 'BMW'::text THEN 4 WHEN 'Maybach'::text THEN 5 ELSE 6 END), (CASE WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.2)) THEN 1 WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.4)) THEN 2 WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.6)) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END), (CASE WHEN ((images_count = 0) OR (images_count IS NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), (abs((price - 347900)))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=60813"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=326.63..327.35 rows=286 width=28) (actual time=218.499..218.501 rows=61 loops=1)"
"        Output: id, (CASE WHEN ((featuring_score)::text < 'C'::text) THEN 1 WHEN ((featuring_score)::text = 'C'::text) THEN 2 WHEN ((featuring_score)::text > 'C'::text) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END), (CASE WHEN (au_rating >= 3) THEN 1 WHEN (au_rating = 0) THEN 2 WHEN (au_rating = 2) THEN 3 WHEN (au_rating = 1) THEN 4 ELSE 6 END), (CASE brand WHEN 'Audi'::text THEN 1 WHEN 'Alpina'::text THEN 2 WHEN 'Artega'::text THEN 3 WHEN 'BMW'::text THEN 4 WHEN 'Maybach'::text THEN 5 ELSE 6 END), (CASE WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.2)) THEN 1 WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.4)) THEN 2 WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.6)) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END), (CASE WHEN ((images_count = 0) OR (images_count IS NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), (abs((price - 347900)))"
"        Sort Key: (CASE WHEN ((cars.featuring_score)::text < 'C'::text) THEN 1 WHEN ((cars.featuring_score)::text = 'C'::text) THEN 2 WHEN ((cars.featuring_score)::text > 'C'::text) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END), (CASE WHEN (cars.au_rating >= 3) THEN 1 WHEN (cars.au_rating = 0) THEN 2 WHEN (cars.au_rating = 2) THEN 3 WHEN (cars.au_rating = 1) THEN 4 ELSE 6 END), (CASE cars.brand WHEN 'Audi'::text THEN 1 WHEN 'Alpina'::text THEN 2 WHEN 'Artega'::text THEN 3 WHEN 'BMW'::text THEN 4 WHEN 'Maybach'::text THEN 5 ELSE 6 END), (CASE WHEN ((abs((cars.price - 347900)))::numeric < ((cars.price)::numeric * 0.2)) THEN 1 WHEN ((abs((cars.price - 347900)))::numeric < ((cars.price)::numeric * 0.4)) THEN 2 WHEN ((abs((cars.price - 347900)))::numeric < ((cars.price)::numeric * 0.6)) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END), (CASE WHEN ((cars.images_count = 0) OR (cars.images_count IS NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), (abs((cars.price - 347900)))"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 33kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=60813"
"        ->  Index Scan using index_cars_v2 on de.cars  (cost=0.42..316.72 rows=286 width=28) (actual time=0.075..205.774 rows=60655 loops=1)"
"              Output: id, CASE WHEN ((featuring_score)::text < 'C'::text) THEN 1 WHEN ((featuring_score)::text = 'C'::text) THEN 2 WHEN ((featuring_score)::text > 'C'::text) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END, CASE WHEN (au_rating >= 3) THEN 1 WHEN (au_rating = 0) THEN 2 WHEN (au_rating = 2) THEN 3 WHEN (au_rating = 1) THEN 4 ELSE 6 END, CASE brand WHEN 'Audi'::text THEN 1 WHEN 'Alpina'::text THEN 2 WHEN 'Artega'::text THEN 3 WHEN 'BMW'::text THEN 4 WHEN 'Maybach'::text THEN 5 ELSE 6 END, CASE WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.2)) THEN 1 WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.4)) THEN 2 WHEN ((abs((price - 347900)))::numeric < ((price)::numeric * 0.6)) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END, CASE WHEN ((images_count = 0) OR (images_count IS NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, abs((price - 347900))"
"              Index Cond: ((cars.price >= 35920) AND (cars.price <= 659880))"
"              Buffers: shared hit=60813"
"Planning Time: 1.118 ms"
"Execution Time: 218.589 ms"
```

I would have expect adding the functional `CASE WHEN` statements on `featuring_score` and `au_rating` to the indexes to produce a better performance, as the index would be pre-sorted according to the first sorting criteria, however it makes exactly no difference. Is my assumption off or do I somehow do something wrong in the index definition.

PS. I have also tried having `price` last in the index, that didn't make any difference either in the query plan - which I'm actually also puzzled by...

PPS. I'm running PostgreSQL 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index has to contain *all* `ORDER BY` entries so that it can be used to avoid the sort:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS index_cars_v2
ON de.cars (
   (CASE WHEN cars.featuring_score < 'C' THEN 1
         WHEN cars.featuring_score = 'C' THEN 2
         WHEN cars.featuring_score > 'C' THEN 3
         ELSE 4
    END),
   (CASE WHEN cars.au_rating >= 3 THEN 1
         WHEN cars.au_rating = 0  THEN 2
         WHEN cars.au_rating = 2  THEN 3
         WHEN cars.au_rating = 1  THEN 4
         ELSE 6
    END),
   (CASE cars.brand
         WHEN 'Audi' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Alpina' THEN 2
         WHEN 'Artega' THEN 3
         WHEN 'BMW' THEN 4
         WHEN 'Maybach' THEN 5
         ELSE 6
    END),
   (CASE WHEN ABS(cars.price - 347900) < cars.price * 0.2 THEN 1
         WHEN ABS(cars.price - 347900) < cars.price * 0.4 THEN 2
         WHEN ABS(cars.price - 347900) < cars.price * 0.6 THEN 3
         ELSE 4
    END),
   (CASE WHEN images_count = 0 OR images_count IS NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END),
   (ABS(cars.price - 347900))
WHERE sales_state = 'onsale' 
   AND is_disabled IS NOT TRUE 
   AND featuring_score IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I seen, didn't know that. The query however varies on the input of the remaining `ORDER BY` clauses, so adding all of them is out of the scope here. Do you see any alternative idea for indexing this query other than the first options (using only `price`) I have suggested myself then?

Comment: If the `ORDER BY` clause varies, all you can do is index for the `WHERE` conditions, like in your first index.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I guess I will have to rethink this entire thing to get a more decent performance. Maybe segment the query by different `featuring_score`s and then query the cars iteratively with more selective queries until I get a sufficient number of cars back